# Significance test for different time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, model

I have two different experimental setups with three replicas each. The data describes the growth of bacteria over time. I am looking for a test to determine whether the time series of the two setups are significantly different (p<0.05). I tried several approaches but did not find a clear solution by now. This is what I tried so far:

**Multiple t-tests**

Since I have two time series with 3 replica each, I have six datapoints for every time. I did a t-test on every timestep, leading to some t-tests being negative (red background, no significant difference) and some positive (green background, significant difference). I would probably need to combine those t-test into one p-value but I don't kow how or whether this is possible.

[image]

Note that this is not the real data (I cannot post the real data here) but artificial data that resembles the real data quite well.

**Model-based**

Inspired by [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17881/hypothesis-testing-and-significance-for-time-series) I tried to fit a model to the data. I guess the ARIMA model is not suitable here, because even with differentiation, the data will not be stationary. I used the [logistic growth](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-biology/ecology-ap/population-ecology-ap/a/exponential-logistic-growth) model instead which describes the data quite well. However, it is unclear to me, how and why I would do an F-test (which tests for variance as far as I know) on the sum of the residuals as the answer on the mentioned question suggests. I fitted the model to all replica and tested the parameters for a significance between the setups with a t-test. In this case, one parameter was significantly different (K) and one was not (r_max), which brings me back to the problem of combination of t-tests.

I don't need a solution to all approaches. I am happy if you can fix one of them or present an entirely different solution. I uploaded the [data](https://we.tl/t-mem061MKED), if anyone wants to try anything with it (link will only be valid for a week).

Comment: There may be some tools in functional time series that would be helpful. For example this paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/23361016.pdf) where in Section 3 there is a test for the equality of means of two functional time series. So maybe you could do something like average the time series from both setups and then run a two-sample test.

Comment: @DavidVeitch thank you. I will try that. Using the mean to describe the dataset seems like some information is lost, but I guess in this case it could be justified.